# My son is already in the UK. Can I buy him a Britrail pass?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

My son in college is in the UK for the semester. I'm going to visit him soon for a week. He doesn't have a Britrail pass, but for our upcoming week of more heavy train use, a pass would be more efficient. I know I can buy myself one (I plan to get an M-pass), but can I buy one for him, even though he is already in the UK? His would need to be an M-pass too.

Comment: You should be able to apply for a pass for your son provided he hasn’t been in the UK for more than 6 months https://www.visitbritainshop.com/world/britrail-mpass/

Comment: @Traveller The website requires you to select an arrival date, which can't be in the past. So are you asserting that it's OK to give an inaccurate arrival date in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I read on the Dutch version of the ['buy your BritRail M pass'](https://www.visitbritainshop.com/nederland/britrail-mpass/) page is that you can enter your date of arrival in the UK till about 6 months after arrival. You may have to adjust the arrival date by hand but when I tried that was possible.

There is however a rule that you may only use such a pass if you are in the UK for 6 months or less and may be asked for travel details out of the UK if there is doubt.

In the FAQ (still in Dutch) I found this information.

> Onze BritRail passen zijn alleen beschikbaar voor klanten met een non-uk paspoort die maximum 6 maanden in de UK verblijven. In geval van inspectie op de trein dient u een bewijs van terugkomst (reisdetails van vlucht, boekingsnummer van trein/ferry) te tonen.

My translation:
Our BritRail passes are only available for customers with a non-UK passport who are in the UK for maximum 6 months. In case of inspection on the train you need to be able to show a proof of return (travel details of flight, booking number of train/ferry).

Before you buy your own, make sure you can get your son a pass, if you want to use the same pass for both of you.

If your son is in the UK for more than 6 months you can not buy such a pass for him.